# Position dataLabel above a certain column Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a stacked back chart, in which I have added an invisible bar to the height of the highest bar. So when a column contains
a small value, this column will still be clickable. In this case, the columns with value 1 would be hardly clickable without the invisible stack.

However, I have a problem with aligning the labels above each column. I know I can use some like:

```
 dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: blue,
    y: -100,
}
```

but that doesn't really work as you can see in the image. The value of the last bar is showing in the bar, which makes it invisible.

[image]

It would be best if I could get the top from a bar in a certain serie, (2nd one in my case) and position the dataLabel a little bit above it. Something like the stackLabels.

I tried something like this, but without succes:

```
$.each(chart.series[1], function (pointIndex, point) {
            if (point !== undefined) {
                var elem = point.graphic.element.getBBox();
                point.dataLabel.attr({ y: elem + 20 });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a lot easier than I thought, I ended up doing the following:

```
var chart = $('#target').highcharts();
var points = chart.series[1].points;


$.each(points, function (pointIndex, point) {
            text = chart.renderer.text(
                'Put whatever you like here',
                point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10,
                point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 20
            ).attr({
                zIndex: 5
            }).add();
        });
```

Code from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-on-chart/) was used.